# Armature: Bones deforming mesh objects in GLTF viewer

Tags: modeling, armature, export, bones, gltf

Hello fellow BlendMasters!

I am trying to make a simple sliding door animation for my GLTF viewer and keep running into this problem:

When i parent my objects (doors) with the separate bones (ctrl + p > Bone) in blender it all looks good, but if i export this scene to GLTF format and look at it in GLTF viewer - doors are misplaced. Misplacing happens even when there are no animations nor actions made.

My blender file looks like that:
[image: initial blender file]

This is what i get in gltf viewer:

[image: gltf viewer]

My final intention is to separatelly start animations of the both doors.
[image: Final intention]

imgur album:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9c6i.jpg

What am i doing wrong? Maybe it is not the right way to do this? In my final file there will be more doors like that, which i want to control individually.

My Blender sample file:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As i found out from glTF Blender Exporter github [issue thread](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/issues/155), this is exporters problem. 
Workaround to this is:

> ...to create joints and weights for this mesh and give full weight to
>   the bone it is assigned to.

That worked for me, so i hope it will help someone like me in the future.

Comment: You could then mark your answer as accepted...